# If $(g\circ f)(n)=n-1$, $(g\circ f)(1)=3$ and $g$ is injective, then $f$ is not invertible

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Given two functions $f,g:N\to N$. It is known that $(g\circ f)(n)=n-1$ for each $n\in N, n\geq2$ and also that $(g\circ f)(1)=3$

The problem: Prove that if $g$ is injective, then $f$ isn't invertible.

Comment: We have $g(f(4)) = g(f(1)) = 3$. Now use injectivity of $g$.

Comment: @player3236 Right, we have the $g(f(4))=g(f(1))$, but what does it give us when it comes to injectivity of g and inverse function f.

Comment: $g(x)=g(y)\implies x=y$. On the other hand, if $f$ fails to be bijective, then $f$ cannot have an inverse.

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are both injective, then also [$(g \circ f)$ is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function#Other_properties). But $(g \circ f)(1)=(g \circ f)(4)$

Comment: @player3236 so how do I implement it, and prove that if g is injective then f doesn't have an inverse function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We see that $g(f(4)) = g(f(1)) = 3$.

Since $g$ is injective, we have $f(4)=f(1)$.

Since $4 \ne 1$, $f$ is not injective.

Therefore $f$ is not bijective and cannot be invertible.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I thought about this, and I found they $f$ is not injective, and found that g(f(4))=g(f(1))=3. So I was really close, but I didn't know the meaning of inverse function and now I understood.